# Configuration Manager (SCCM) Clients not updating their status

Tags: sccm, configuration-management

I have issues where the configuration manager CAS server is showing the clients as "Pending System Restart". When you look at the client it's referring to, it shows the status as having been sent, and no status of restarting pending is shown in the registry (client was restarted anyway).

Re-running the summarization and refreshing has not worked over a period of hours.

[image]

The client log (server1) files below:
[image]

Is there any way to clear the client status on the CAS server, and is there a fault with the Management Points in not passing on the status messages?

Comment: I'm assuming restarting the clients didn't help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, restarting the agent service or the client didn't help.

Comment: @BigHomie Have you resolved this before?  I'm seeing basically the same thing occur here.

Comment: @ALX9R Sorry I didn't check this sooner, will add a script that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a script that does fix the issue most of the time. This was buried in the SCCM 2012 unleashed book.

Copy this to .vbs, run it on the client machine having issues. Then restart the sms service and re-run your cycle (software update, etc).

That should force it to recheck it's check state.

```
' Initialize the UpdatesStore variable.
dim newCCMUpdatesStore
' Create the COM object.
set newCCMUpdatesStore = CreateObject ("Microsoft.CCM.UpdatesStore")
' Refresh the server compliance state by running the RefreshServerComplianceState method.
newCCMUpdatesStore.RefreshServerComplianceState
' Output success message.
wscript.echo "Ran RefreshServerComplianceState."
```

Comment: No problems. It's an older script but you'll be amazed at how well it fixes stuck clients.

Comment: Just to be clear.  Do you run this on the client?

Comment: Correct, run on the client. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To build on Mark's answer, you can this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -AsJob {(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.CCM.UpdatesStore).RefreshServerComplianceState()}
```